# How can I avoid redundancy in nearly identically criteria?

Tags: grails

Imagine I have the following query:

```
def result = Test.createCriteria().list(params) {
     // image here a lot of assocs, criterias, ...
}
```

In many cases you need the row count of the query above, e.g. list actions of many controllers.

```
def resultTotal = Test.createCriteria().list(params) {
     // Imagine here a lot of assocs, criterias, ...
     // Change to the criteria above is only the projection block
     projections { rowCount() }
}
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

1. Extract the Criteria creation to a conditional factory/builder method;
2. Use [named queries](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/namedQueries.html);
3. Use named query parameters (and Groovy code!) to alter the query "on the fly", like:

.

```
static namedQueries = {
    byLocation { Location location ->
        if (location) {
        ... // some more criteria logic
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't paginating the results of the query, you can simply do the following after the first query is invoked:

```
def resultTotal = result?.size()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the same set of query being used at many places, I create them as a closure and change its delegate to the criteria in question. 
For example :

```
def query = {
   projections{
       rowCount()
     }
   eq('type', myType)
  }

 def criteria = Customer.createCriteria()
        query.delegate = criteria
        myType = CustomerType.guest
        List records = criteria.list(params) {
            query()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use totalCount like this:

```
def list() {
    def myInstanceList = MyInstance.createCriteria().list(params){
        eq('name', params.name)
    }
    [myInstanceList: myInstanceList, myInstanceListTotal: myInstanceList.totalCount]
}
```